# gnome3: Which program do I use to set an icon for my user account?

Tags: gnome

I had a hard time installing Gnome3, and I'm afraid that i brok'd something.

If I click on my user account in the top right corner, and then click on the default icon. The menu shuts and I expect that a program would open to change the icon, but nothing happens.

So my question is: Which program will set this user icon for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the "System Settings" (gnome-control-center) and go to "User Accounts" (in the section "System"). There you select your own profile and then click on the profile picture to change it.
You can also change others profile pictures if you are an administrator and use the "Unlock" button in the top-right edge of the window.

Comment: If you are using an older version of gnome than I do (I've got 3.8) it could be that some bits are different, but afaik there weren't so many changes on this since gnome 3 departed.